# How to achieve programmatic serial number and other details of a specific USB device?

Tags: c, winapi

How can I get information about specific USB?
Information such as serial number, manufacturer number, product number, etc.

I can get the handle to USB by this func

```
CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\E:", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
```

But from now on I'm pretty stuck,**HidD_GetHidGuid**, returns only Details of the hard disk,and **GetRawInputDeviceList** and **GetRawInputDeviceInfo** not allow me to get information about USB (by name, as in the example with the function **CreateFile**)

When I try the following code:

```
DeviceIoControl(HandelUsb, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, NULL, 0, &dg, sizeof(DISK_GEOMETRY),&dwReturned, NULL);
MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA msnd = { 0 };
DeviceIoControl(HandelUsb, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER, NULL, 0, &msnd,sizeof(MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA), &dwReturned, NULL);
```

I always get a serial number 0 ...
(I tried on different USB devices)

Comment: The device you're accessing is a disk volume, not a USB device. That the volume resides on a USB drive is irrelevant. Had you opened the USB device proper, you'd get the information you seek. You need to figure out what disk the `E:` volume resides on, then get information about that disk, and from there get information about the USB device the disk is on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SetupDi](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/259695) functions. Take look on [SetupDiGetClassDevs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550956(v=vs.85).aspx) function which will return all attached devices. For USB devices use "USB" enumerator.